# Double curly braces in PHP class - how ti use them to generate random string from 2 strings and return the value?

Tags: php, random, generator, curly-braces

I stumbled on a script that generates random names from two different types of words in an array. Code is following:

```
    protected static $techTerms = array('AddOn', 'Algorithm', 'Architect', 'Array', 'Asynchronous', 'Avatar', 'Band', 'Base', 'Beta', 'Binary');

    protected static $culinaryTerms = array('Appetit', 'Bake', 'Beurre', 'Bistro', 'Blend', 'Boil', 'Bouchees', 'Brew', 'Buffet', 'Caffe', 'Caffeine', 'Cake');

    protected static $companyNameFormats = array(
        '{{techTerm}}{{culinaryTerm}}',
        '{{techTerm}}{{techTerm}}',
        '{{culinaryTerm}}{{techTerm}}'
    );

    public static function techTerm()
    {
        return static::randomElement(static::$techTerms);
    }

    public static function culinaryTerm()
    {
        return static::randomElement(static::$culinaryTerms);
    }

    public function companyName()
    {
        $format = static::randomElement(static::$companyNameFormats);

        return $this->generator->parse($format);
    }
```

Basically, the script should create and return a random combination of words as defined in `$companyNameFormats`. This script requires Faker\Factory, but I'd like to make it independent. At this point, there are 2 problems:

`randomElement` as an undefined method, and `generator->parse` as `Call to a member function parse() on null`

I've managed to modify the script and make it work, but I am interested in how can I use the {{}} as given in `$companyNameFormats`  and return the result without using an external library?

The modified script is as follows:

```
    protected static function companyNameFormats()
    {
        $techArray = [];
        $techArray[] = self::techTerm();
        $culinaryArray = [];
        $culinaryArray[] = self::culinaryTerm();

        $result = array(
            array_merge($techArray, $culinaryArray),
            array_merge($techArray, $culinaryArray),
            array_merge($culinaryArray, $techArray),
            array_merge($techArray, $culinaryArray),
            array_merge($culinaryArray, $techArray)
        );

        return $result;
    }

    public static function techTerm()
    {
        $techTermKey = array_rand(static::$techTerms, 1);
        $techTermValue = static::$techTerms[$techTermKey];

        return $techTermValue;
    }

    public static function culinaryTerm()
    {
        $culinaryTermsKey = array_rand(static::$culinaryTerms, 1);
        $culinaryTermsValue = static::$culinaryTerms[$culinaryTermsKey];

        return $culinaryTermsValue;
    }

    public function companyName()
    {
        $companyNameKey = array_rand(static::companyNameFormats(), 1);
        $companyNameValue = static::companyNameFormats()[$companyNameKey];

        return $companyNameValue;
    }
```

Comment: If `randomElement` is undefined, how did the script work in the first place? Also, why not check out how Faker creates the strings, and reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: @NicoHaase it uses an external library and this class extends a class from the external library

Comment: Then why not either review the code in that library to mimik the behaviour, or keep that dependency to not duplicate all that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're probably doing something like `preg_replace`.

Quick and dirty example:

```
class Foo {

protected static array $foods = ["Pie", "Cake", "Yoghurt"];
protected static array $animals = ["Dog", "Cat", "Giraffe"];

protected static array $formats = [
    "{{food}} {{animal}}", 
    "{{animal}} {{food}}"
];

public function get():string{
    $format = $this->getRandomElement(self::$formats);

    
    $format = preg_replace(
        "/{{animal}}/",
        $this->getRandomElement(self::$animals),
        $format
    );
    
    return preg_replace(
        "/{{food}}/",
        $this->getRandomElement(self::$foods),
        $format
    );
}

protected function getRandomElement(array $elements):string{
    return $elements[random_int(0, count($elements) - 1)];
}
}

echo (new Foo())->get(); // Cat Yoghurt
```

Comment: This is better than the bunch of arrays I've used. I'll give it a try now.

Comment: This code gives `syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)'`  on the first definition 'protected static array $foods ' but I got your point.

Comment: @milenmk yes, I should have mentioned that this is for  PHP > 7.4 (types in property declaration). Remove the typehint from the class properties to fix that error for PHP < 7.4

Comment: Is there any need to use `preg_replace` here? Why not use `str_replace` if you don't use any regular expression?

Comment: @NicoHaase That should also work, and is certainly the better choice, though I imagine the performance hit here is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @Kyrre code, this is the final working example:

```
protected static $techTerms = array('AddOn', 'Algorithm', 'Architect', 'Array', 'Asynchronous', 'Avatar', 'Band', 'Base', 'Beta', 'Binary');

    protected static $culinaryTerms = array('Appetit', 'Bake', 'Beurre', 'Bistro', 'Blend', 'Boil', 'Bouchees', 'Brew', 'Buffet', 'Caffe', 'Caffeine', 'Cake');

    protected static $companyNameFormats = array(
        '{{techTerm}} {{culinaryTerm}}',
        '{{techTerm}} {{techTerm}}',
        '{{culinaryTerm}} {{techTerm}}'
    );

    public static function techTerm()
    {
        return static::getRandomElement(static::$techTerms);
    }

    public static function culinaryTerm()
    {
        return static::getRandomElement(static::$culinaryTerms);
    }

    protected static function getRandomElement(array $elements): string
    {
        return $elements[random_int(0, count($elements) - 1)];
    }

    public function get(): string
    {
        $format = $this->getRandomElement(self::$companyNameFormats);


        $format = preg_replace(
            "/{{techTerm}}/",
            $this->getRandomElement(self::$techTerms),
            $format
        );

        return preg_replace(
            "/{{culinaryTerm}}/",
            $this->getRandomElement(self::$culinaryTerms),
            $format
        );
    }
```

Comment: Is there any need to use `preg_replace` here? Why not use `str_replace` if you don't use any regular expression?

Comment: @NicoHaase because `str_replace` returns `{{culinaryTerm}} {{techTerm}}` instead of the items from the arrays

Comment: ....if you used `str_replace('{{culinaryTerm}}', $this->getRandomElement, $format)`, how should this work different from `preg_replace`?